# Jquery read xml block

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I read this XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parse version="beta" release='1'>
    **<env str="p1" open='config' close='end'/>
    <env str="p2" open='edit' close="next"/>**
    <open str="config system global" jmp="1">
        <set str="set hostname" nomr="hostname"></set>
    </open>
    <open  str="config system interface" jmp='6'>
        <open str="edit" norm="intfisdef" jmp='2'>
            <set str="set ip" norm="intfisip"/>
            <set str="set alias" norm="intnom"/>
            <open str="config secondaryip" jmp='0'>
                <open str="edit" norm="intfisindsecdef" jmp='1'> 
                    <set str="set ip" norm="intfisindsecip"/>
                </open>
            </open>
        </open>
    </open>
 </parse>
```

With this function:

```
function alertit2(jqueryObject) {
    jqueryObject.each(function() {
        node = (this);
        str = $(node).attr("str");
        NodeName = node.nodeName;
        console.log("Node Name=" + NodeName + "\nstr=" + str + "\ncmd=" + StringaComando);

        if (NodeName == "open" && StringaComando.substr(0, str.length) == str) {
            FindOpen++;
            alert ("find this");
            return node;
        }
    });
    StringaComando = "";    
}
```

I call `alertit2` when `StringaComando` is valid ("config system global"):,

```
if (FindOpen==0)
    var Figlio = alertit2($(XML).find('parse').children());
else
    alertit2($(Figlio));
```

Output is

> Node Name=env str=p1 cmd=config system global
>
> Node Name=env str=p2 cmd=config system global
>
> Node Name=open str=config system global cmd=config system global
>
> find this
>
> Node Name=open str=config system interface cmd=config system global
>
> **> Node Name=env str=p1 cmd=set access-banner disable**
>
> Node Name=env str=p2 cmd=set access-banner disable
>
> Node Name=open str=config system global cmd=set access-banner
>   disable
>
> Node Name=open str=config system interface cmd=set access-banner disable
>
> Node Name=env str=p1 cmd=set admin-concurrent enable
>
> Node Name=env str=p2 cmd=set admin-concurrent enable
>
> Node Name=env str=p1 cmd=set admin-concurrent enable

My question:
Why i see node: `Node *Name=env* str=p1 cmd=set access-banner disable`?

The aim is that once you find "config system global" continue parsing with the open sets contained in block `<open str=config system global...`

Thanks

Comment: Where does this "StringaComando" variable come from?  Obviously that's where that "set access-banner disable" string is stored, but why?

Answer (score 1):

Return `false` rather than `node` from your function within the `.each()` loop when your condition on `StringaComando` is met.

By returning `node`, you're returning a true-ish value that signals that the `.each()` loop should continue; return `false` to signal that it should not continue to the next item.